# It is possible to verify the computation of a hash function without actually proving it in zero knowledge?

Tags: hash, zero-knowledge-proofs, one-way-function, snarks, starks

Let me first introduce the context: Let's say that we have a hash function evaluation: $$h = H(x, y),$$ where $x$ and $y$ are the public and the private input of the hash function $H$, respectively.

Then, if I want to prove to someone that this computation have been computed properly without actually disclosing $x$, then I have to create a zero-knowledge proof of knowledge $\pi$ (which could be obtained through general purpose ZKPoK such us SNARKS, STARKS, ...) of an $x$ such that $h = H(x, y)$.
Until this point, everything is okey.

What if I do want someone else to verify the hash evaluation without revealing the private input $x$, not going through generic purpose ZKPoK; and **more importantly**: keeping some hash function [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Properties) such as determinism, uniformity and universality?

My first idea to solve this question is to find a function $f$ such that:

1. $f(x)$ can be made public (so that anyone can easily check the computation $H(f(x), y)$).
2. $f(x)$ also satisfies determinism,uniformity and universality.

In fact, if such a function $f$ exist, then I could just replace $H$ with $f$. Let's say that what I am trying to find is some computation that shares some of the properties that hash functions have but being much more efficiently (i.e., without the need of generic purpose proofs) verificable.

A second idea is to substitute the hashing mechanism by something else (e.g., encryption concatenated with a signature ...) that could be efficiently verifiable while at the same time keeping the mentioned properties.

Comment: What is the status of $y$?

Comment: What do you mean by status?

Comment: Is it publicly known? Or is it secret?

Comment: $x$ is the public input and $y$ is the private input.

Comment: If $H$, $f(x)$ is also public, everyone can check $h= H(f(x), y)$, no?

Comment: Exactly, but I want $f(x)$ to also being a deterministic computation, uniform and universal. In other words, I need $f(x)$ to be a deterministic computation that reveals nothing about the pre-image $x$ and that the risk of collisions is negligible.

Comment: "that reveals nothing"=> Be more precise.

Comment: Is that okey if I say that I want $f(x)$ to be pre-image resistant?

Comment: From your description, it somehow sounds that you are looking for a commitment scheme, e.g. a Pedersen commitment.

Comment: @RubenDeSmet The problem is that a commitment does not look like a random element.  For instance, you can just append some amount of 0s at the end of the commitments ,and then, you easily distinguish a commitment from a random element.

Comment: I don't see how; a standard Pedersen commitment $C = xG + yH$ is perfectly hiding, and afaik undistinguishable from random. On the other hand; that would integrate your $y$ variable into the $f(x)$ function and require it to be uniform random, so it's not strictly what you're after.